# INVALID_FIELD, All accounts must have the same current owner and new owner.: [OwnerId]

Tags: apex, after-trigger

I am trying to cascade the same ownerid across all contact owners within an Account Contact Relation hierarchy. I wrote a pretty basic after update trigger on an account to accomplish this.

When all records are owned by the same person, it updates correctly. When there is a mix of ownerids, I receive "INVALID_FIELD, All accounts must have the same current owner and new owner.: [OwnerId]" Please note: Person accounts are enabled in this Org.

Basic Logic

```
 list<contact> Contacts = new list<contact>();
    for(AccountContactRelation r: [select id, 
                                   AccountId,
                                   contactid, 
                                   contact.ownerid, 
                                   contact.owner.Name 
                                   from AccountContactRelation 
                                   where AccountID in: AccountOwnerMap.keyset() 
                                  ]){
                                      system.debug('r: ' + r);
                                      if(r.AccountID!=null && AccountOwnerMap.containskey(r.AccountID)){
                                          Contact c = new Contact(id=r.Contactid);
                                          c.ownerid = AccountOwnerMap.get(r.AccountID);
                                          Contacts.add(c);    
                                      } 
                                  }
    system.debug('Contacts: ' + Contacts);
    //Update Contacts
    if(Contacts.size()>0){
        update Contacts;
    }
```

Similar issue with no clear answers below.

- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005fBzQAI
- https://getsatisfaction.com/dataloader/topics/issue-in-jitterbit-8-16-13-1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318173/salesforce-triggering-contact-pa-owner-change-when-account-owner-is-changed-fa

Comment: I am facing same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

You can call the update from within a future method to fix this problem